# Proj4j projection results wildly inaccurate

Tags: java, geospatial, azimuth, proj, geodesic-sphere

I'm trying to use EquidistantAzimuthalProjection to get the latitude/longitude of a new location based on its relative distance and bearing to a known location. Here is my source code:

```
import org.osgeo.proj4j.ProjCoordinate
import org.osgeo.proj4j.proj.EquidistantAzimuthalProjection

EquidistantAzimuthalProjection proj = new EquidistantAzimuthalProjection(43.694195, -79.262262)
proj.setUnits(org.osgeo.proj4j.units.Units.METRES)
ProjCoordinate src = new ProjCoordinate(10, 10)
ProjCoordinate dst = new ProjCoordinate
proj.inverseProject(src, dst)
```

Since I already set units to Meters, and 10m is a very small distance. The result should not be too far from latitude/longitude of the starting point  (43.694195, -79.262262). Hoevever the result yield by inverseProject is:

```
(138.66016814892942,-16.49593292366875)
```

The document clearly states that output unit of inverseProject is degree and input unit is consistent with the Projection itself (which is already set to meters). Do I miss something in invoking this library?

Thanks a lot for your experience